# Using expect to get output from ssh

Tags: python, ssh, expect

I am trying to use `expect` to automate a task as part of a larger python program and am having a lot of trouble getting the stdout of the ssh command being run on a remote machine. I have not used `expect` before and haven't had success finding the solution on the man page.

I need to use expect to automate some interactions before actually being able to run this command, but I removed them here to simplify the question.

Here is a simplified example of the program:

```
import subprocess

expect = """
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF

spawn ssh some_machine ls
expect eof
puts "$expect_out(buffer)"
"""

output = subprocess.check_output(expect, shell=True)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
b'spawn ssh some_machine ls\r\n116029\r\nArchive\r\n\r\n(buffer)\n'
```

It appears to contain the spawn command as well as "(buffer)" at the end. I'm not sure why this is occurring. I am trying to only get the results of the `ls`.

If I turn on debug mode in expect, I see the `expect_out(buffer)` being set to what I would like to return, but the `puts` does not reflect this.

Output:

```
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d
set argc 0
set argv0 "/usr/bin/expect"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {1753}
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "116029\r\nArchive\r\n"
<wrong output as above>
```

Comment: Why are you using `expect` here?  You're just running a command and reading it's standard output.  You could just run `subprocess.check_output('ssh some_machine ls', shell=True)`.

Comment: I simplified the script for example purposes, but I need use it to automate some interaction before I can collect the output.

Comment: Also, your shell script `expect` is missing a terminal `EOF` to match the `<<EOF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress the log output from expect with the `log_user` command:

```
log_user 0
spawn ssh some_host ls
expect eof
puts "$expect_out(buffer)"
```

Without `log_user 0`, I get:

```
$ expect -f sample.tcl
spawn ssh some_host ls
file1
file2
```

By adding `log_user 0`, I get:

```
$ expect -f sample.tcl
file1
file2
```

There seems to be some oddness when you feed expect the script via stdin, but the following seems to work:

```
import subprocess
import tempfile

expect = """
log_user 0
spawn ssh some_host ls < /dev/null
expect eof
puts "$expect_out(buffer)"
"""

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fd:
    fd.write(expect)
    fd.flush()
    fd.seek(0)
    output = subprocess.check_output(['expect', fd.name])

print(output)
```

Comment: The only output I get from doing this is: `b'(buffer)\n'`

Comment: There is something missing from your comment, but I think I see the behavior you were trying to describe.  Taking a look...

Comment: Yes, it does work using the sample.tcl. But when I use in python, it is not working properly and the output appears to only be above. I will keep investigating...